# RubyMine - cannot login to the github.com using given credentials

Tags: github, rubymine

I have installed RubyMine on OS X and Windows 7, and neither can connect to GitHub.

Both computers have SSH configured and can connect to GitHub using SSH on the commandline.

Both give me the same error when attempting to configure GitHub in Preferences:

[image]

Is this a known issue, or is there something else I need to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would log into GitHub with your email address and password, but for RubyMine you need to provide you username (not email) and password.

If your SSH keys are valid then you should not have any issues logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've specified key and its password propely, note that the key file must be in **OpenSSH** format. You can convert it using `puttygen.exe` on Windows or `ssh-keygen` on Mac.